# Installing distributed tensorflow on Mac

Tags: tensorflow

Could someone please provide the link which shows how to do the above? I tried all the relevant places, but I could not find the procedure. If I just install TF for Mac as described on the TF website, does that give me the distributed version by default?

---After installing the GPU version of TF and running the test script given in the answer---

```
(tensorflow) acbc32a44fc1:~ z001jly$ python test.py 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.1.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.dylib locally
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
import tensorflow as tf
File "/Users/z001jly/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *
File "/Users/z001jly/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "/Users/z001jly/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
File "/Users/z001jly/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in    swig_import_helper_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/z001jly/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.7.5.dylib

Referenced from: /Users/z001jly/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
Reason: image not found
```

The script runs successfully if I use it with the CPU version of TF.

Comment: what if you try CPU-only binary? (export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.10.0-py2-none-any.whl)

Comment: ok, I googled and found out the symlink issue. So, the installation is fixed. Will try your script now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's part of official TensorFlow binaries. You could run script below to check if it works, should see "Success"

```
import subprocess
import tensorflow as tf
import time
import sys

flags = tf.flags
flags.DEFINE_string("port1", "12222", "port of worker1")
flags.DEFINE_string("port2", "12223", "port of worker2")
flags.DEFINE_string("task", "", "internal use")
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS

# setup local cluster from flags
host = "127.0.0.1:"
cluster = {"worker": [host+FLAGS.port1, host+FLAGS.port2]}
clusterspec = tf.train.ClusterSpec(cluster).as_cluster_def()

def run():
  dtype=tf.int32
  params_size = 1

  with tf.device("/job:worker/task:0"):
    params = tf.get_variable("params", [params_size], dtype,
                             initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
  with tf.device("/job:worker/task:1"):
    update_variable = tf.get_variable("update_variable", [params_size], dtype,
                                      initializer=tf.ones_initializer)
    add_op = params.assign_add(update_variable)

  init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

  # launch distributed service
  def runcmd(cmd): subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  runcmd("python "+sys.argv[0]+" --task=0")
  runcmd("python "+sys.argv[0]+" --task=1")
  time.sleep(1)

  sess = tf.Session("grpc://"+host+FLAGS.port1)
  sess.run(init_op)
  print("Adding 1 on %s to variable on %s"%(update_variable.device,
                                            params.device))
  result = sess.run(add_op)
  if result == [1]:
    print("Success")


if __name__=='__main__':
  if not FLAGS.task:
    run()

  else: # Launch TensorFlow server
    server = tf.train.Server(clusterspec,
                             job_name="worker",
                             task_index=int(FLAGS.task),
                             config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
    server.join()
```

Comment: If I use the CPU version, the script runs successfully.

Comment: Could you please tell why the script fails for the GPU version of TF

Comment: looks like some kind of problem with cuda loading, maybe need to turn off sip (System Integrity Protection)